# Inline assembly equivalent of _InterlockedCompareExchange128

Tags: c, windows, inline-assembly

Due to certain restrictions at work I am required to use the Windows WDK version 6000 to compile my code.  However, I find myself needing the _InterlockedCompareExchange128 compiler intrinsic in my code.  This intrinsic was not introduced until WDK version 7600.  In doing my internet searches it seems like the assembly instruction I need is "lock cmpxchg16b."  However, I am not an assembly programmer and don't have a clue how to use this from from C code.  Can x64 programs have inline assembly?  Or, do I need to include a .asm file in my project with the appropriate assembly?  Can anyone provide me some guidance and code?

Comment: No assembly code in programs that target x64.  It is [an intrinsic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb514094%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) available in VS2008 and up.

Comment: So, basically I'm stuck?  I can't use assembly or work around the issue?  The only way is to upgrade my compiler?  Unfortunately that won't work.  Like I said, I am forced to use this specific compiler at work. <sigh>

Comment: Sounds to me like you need [this site](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/)

Comment: Turns out that I can include .asm files into my project.  Now, I just need to figure out how to code the assembly file and how to invoke that from C.  Any help or pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: On the C side, use `extern`. Make sure the calling conventions match. Depending on the calling convention, you may need underscores or @'s in the function name on the asm side.